# What is the LCM of $3^{2001}-1$ and $3^{2001}+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

What is the LCM of $3^{2001}-1$ and $3^{2001}+1$?

I can not get whether the GCF is $2$ or more than that.

Comment: This question makes zero sense. Your title asks something, and your post asks something else.

Comment: @AhaanRungta, finding the GCF and the LCM are pretty much the same problem.

Comment: What? $$ \text { } $$

Comment: @AhaanRungta: For non-zero integers $a,b$, we have $$ab=\operatorname{gcf}(a,b)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),$$ so if we know one, then we know the other.

Comment: Sure, fine. Still, my flag was helpful.

Comment: @SherlockWatson Please ask a new question. Changing this one will invalidate the answer, which addressed your old question. Also, please make sure that the question body can be understood *without* the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $b=3a+4$, where $a=3^{2001}-1$ and $b=3^{2002}+1$. So the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must divide $4$. So it is either $2$ or $4$. It is quite easy to see that $a$ isn't a multiple of $4$, so the GCD equals $2$.

Comment: (And therefore the LCM is $\frac {ab}2$...)

Comment: Why is it so obvious that $4\nmid a$?

Comment: @dfeuer Well, $3 \equiv -1 \mod 4$, so $3^{2001}-1 \equiv (-1)^{2001}-1 \mod 4$, and $(-1)^{2001}-1 = -2$ is not a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Of course. Amazing how simple tricks fall out of one's head.

Comment: Also, $3^{2000}=(9)^{1000}\equiv1\pmod 8\implies 3^{2001}\equiv3\pmod8$ and $3^{2002}\equiv9\equiv1\pmod8$